Working principle of the Zener diode acting as a voltage regulator in a circuit
In this simple circuit,

the Zener diode regulates a constant voltage across the load.
I don't understand how the Zener diode is affecting the voltage drop across the resistor, making it so that the voltage is maintained? What are the internal workings behind this phenomena. I want to intuitively understand what is happening with the electrons and atoms. I'm going to sound dumb but how does the resistor know the breakdown voltage of the Zener diode and then adjust itself according to it?

Consider the Zener as a voltage clamp - if the voltage across the load starts going above the Zener voltage, the diode starts conducting, which pulls more current through the 'dropping' resistor which increases the voltage dropped across it until the voltage across the load is the Zener voltage.

Just as an aside, the Zener in your schematic is oriented the wrong way.  This circuit will regulate Vz to the forward voltage drop, probably about 0.7V.  The Zener has to be reverse biased to exploit the breakdown characteristic.


I don't understand how the Zener diode is affecting the voltage drop across the resistor,

From Kirchhoff's Voltage Law (KVL) the voltage across the zener plus the voltage across the dropping resistor is equal to the voltage supplied at the input terminals.
But the IV curve of the zener diode (in the zener operating regime) is very steep, so any increase in applied voltage above the zener knee voltage appears almost entirely across the dropping resistor, rather than across the zener.
KVL also tells us that the voltage across the load resistor is equal to the voltage across the zener. Since the voltage across the zener is nearly constant, the voltage across the load is also nearly constant.

I want to intuitively understand what is happening with the electrons and atoms.

In zener operation, current flows in "reverse" through the PN junction by quantum tunneling.

I'm going to sound dumb but how does the resistor know the breakdown voltage of the Zener diode and then adjust itself according to it?

The resistor doesn't know anything. The resistor has an IV curve. The zener has an IV curve. When you put the zener in parallel with the load resistor, KVL (the circuit theory name for the fact the electrostatic field is conservative) tells you that the voltage across them must be equal. But the IV curve of the zener says that if you try to increase the voltage across it beyond the zener knee voltage, current increases very quickly. The dropping resistor then ensures that rather than current in the overall circuit increasing quickly, voltage is dropped across the dropping resistor rather than across the zener and the load.

Small nitpick: Most so called Zener diodes are not really Zener diodes, as the current is not only due to Zener tunnelling, but also due to avalanche breakdown. For devices with a higher breakdown voltage (Wikipedia says above ~6V for silicon devices) the avalanche breakdown dominates.

@SebastianRiese fair point but I deliberately kept the part about the "electrons and atoms" terse because I don't think a full answer (requiring a semester or two of solid state) would actually help OP to understand the circuit they're asking about.

Yes for the question at hand it is not directly relvant (and this did not keep me from upvoting).

Here's an alternate way to think about it. (I hope this easy to imagine, but I'm not going to tell you how the diode actually works.)

If you replaced the zener diode with a resistor, then it and the "dropping" resistor would form a voltage divider.
OK, but let's replace the zener with a variable resistor. Turning the knob would let you adjust the output voltage. Turn it to reduce the variable resistance, and the output voltage goes down. Turn it the other way, and the voltage goes up.
Now, let's add a volt meter, and let's invoke a demon who will keep their eye on the meter and their hand on the knob. Command the demon to turn the knob as needed to maintain a constant output voltage, and that's pretty close to how the zener behaves.

how does the [dropping] resistor know...?

It doesn't. The dropping resistor only needs to obey Ohm's Law. The "smarts"—the demon with its eye on the meter and its hand on the knob—is all inside the zener package.
